# Why does the canvas not render on iPhone with paper.js

Tags: iphone, html, canvas, paperjs

I've been having trouble for quite some time. I need to get the canvas working on a mobile web app of mine but it seems to be having trouble with paper.js.

I have set my viewport to the following:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
```

And the canvas element:

```
<canvas id="canvas" resize="true"></canvas>
```

But the canvas never seems to render at ALL.

I hope I've given enough information. I'm almost certain that I have no problems from the JavaScript side.

Go easy on me please!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you know it's possible to debug javascript issues by stepping through your code running on the iphone in safari using safari on your mac?

Usually when I run into issues like this, it saves me!

Here's a link that will help you do this: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow-tutorials/quick-tip-using-web-inspector-to-debug-mobile-safari/

If you would like to learn more about paperjs, check out this screencast I created: http://tagtree.tv/canvas-with-paper-js